# MySQL truncating results, causing Warning: array_multisort(): Array sizes are inconsistent

Tags: php, mysql, truncate

I have two arrays. Each is being pulled from MySQL via the following;

```
$query ="SELECT country,";
$query.="GROUP_CONCAT(report) AS reports, ";
$query.="GROUP_CONCAT(topic) AS topics, ";
$query.="FROM reports GROUP BY country";
```

So, it is giving me two strings like this:

```
   reports[$i] = 2011-05-11 A,2011-05-11 B,2011-05-11 C
   topics[$i]  = A,B,C
```

And it is working just fine, however, when the reports string is getting too long, MySQL just truncates it, and then I am throwing

```
Warning: array_multisort(): Array sizes are inconsistent
```

Becuse I am exploding the string down the line.

Obviously this is ruining my program. But I don't know what to do, I am kind of in a crisis, because my boss said he was going to have the whole company start to use it. How can I make MySQL not truncate results?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Set [group_concat_max_len](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/server-system-variables.html#sysvar_group_concat_max_len) to higher value.
Personally, I would rewrite code not to use group_concat function, but retreive all records instead.

Comment: Thank you so much, I was panicking so HARD I couldn't even think. Hah, this project has been three months long now. Thank you so much AGAIN :)

Comment: @RVWard No problem. That what this site is for, right? Community rocks! :)

Comment: And be careful you should set it globally (`SET GLOBAL`) or it will be set for the current session otherwise!

Comment: You guys do ROCK :) I could try to mess around with it to not group_concat, I would just have to rethink how the program would logically function.

Comment: Gah it keeps reverting back to truncation.

Comment: Did you set it globally?  What `show variables like 'group_concat_max_len';` says?

Answer (score 1):

group_concat_max_len is set in the mysql configuration file by the way.  You'll need to restart mysql afterward.